# Xcode 4.3.2, GIT, and Localizable.strings: editor being confused

Tags: xcode, git, localizable.strings

I've installed GIT last week for the Xcode project I'm working one, and since then, I'm having all kind of weird issues. 
The one that really annoys me right now is that when I edit my localizable.strings (I have French and English text) they both become identical in Xcode, i.e. if I edit the english one, and then open the french one, it is displayed with the english text. But if I go edit the file directly on the disk with a text editor, it still contains the right text. The only way I have found to display it correctly is to quit Xcode and reopen it.

So is there a bug with GIT and Localizable file ?

And while am at it: if I quit Xcode while the Organizer is opened showing the Repositories, it 
just won't quit. The editor windows close, but the organizer stays open and from there the only way to quit is to kill Xcode.

thanks,
Benoit

Comment: My GIT folder is on a Windows server.

Comment: I just got an error:  The document "Localizable.strings" is on a volume that does not support permanent version storage". Is it possible that Git doesn't like the fact that the files are not the Mac itself ?

Answer (score 0):

I've moved my GIT back to my local Mac disk, and everything is working fine now. 
So I'll assume it was some kind of security/communication problem between the Mac and the Windows server.